# Installing MS Message Queuing on Windows XP by Command Line

Tags: windows-xp, command-line-interface, windows-service, message-queuing

I developed an application that needs MS Message Queuing to work.
But it's really boring to have to go to the control panel of every computer where it's going to be running and go to Control Panel - Add/Remove Programs - Windows Components - Install Message Queuing.
So I would like to do that operation automatically, while running the setups.

Is there a Command Line instruction to install MSMQ?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun question.

Via [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778216(WS.10).aspx):

To run Message Queuing unattended setup, type the following command at the command prompt in the Windows system folder:

sysocmgr.exe /i:sysoc.inf /u: *path and file name of answer file*

It looks like your answer file should contain:

```
[Components]
msmq_Core = on
Reminst = on
```

If it's a client, you'll need another section in the answer file pointing to your server:

```
[msmq]
SupportingServer = *UNC path of Message Queueing server*
```

There are a few more options depending on your situation.  More details on Sysocmgr and the answer file [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222444).

Comment: Thanks Kara!

I just had to change the answer file in order to also install the triggers and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a batch file with the follow also works:

```
;@ECHO OFF
;sysocmgr.exe /i:sysoc.inf /u:%0
;GOTO Finished


[Components]
msmq_Core = ON
msmq_LocalStorage = ON
msmq_ADIntegrated = ON
msmq_TriggersService = ON
msmq_HTTPSupport = OFF
msmq_RoutingSupport = OFF
msmq_MQDSService = OFF

;:Finished
```

Found this info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/06/19/minimalist-setup-script-for-msmq-unattended-installation.aspx).

Comment: This may work (I've no way of testing it), but Kara's solution seems far cleaner...